# How to load a Google Earth map zoomed in rather than starting from space?

Tags: javascript, geospatial, google-earth-plugin

I have a set view to start on when loading the Google Earth API from my website, but it starts from space and then zooms in rather than starting on this zoomed-in view. This is wonky for the viewer particularly because my view is from the north looking south, so the Earth does a whirl on the way in:
http://www.colorado.edu/geography/cartpro/cartography2/fall2011/bartel/projects/project3_tungurahua/tungurahua_hazards.html

The map loads into an iframe. I'd like to toggle between various kmls without changing the zoomed view, as well, but I'll post that question separately. I've looked around for answers but haven't found anything specific to this--if I missed a post about this, I'm happy to check it out if someone can point me in the right direction.

Here's the code:

```
      var ge;
google.load("earth", "1");

function init() {
   google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
}

function initCB(instance) {
   ge = instance;
   ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
   // set navigation controls
   ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);
   // to fetch a  KML file and show it
function finished(object) {
  if (!object) {
    // wrap alerts in API callbacks and event handlers
    // in a setTimeout to prevent deadlock in some browsers
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Bad or null KML.');
    }, 0);
    return;
  }
  ge.getFeatures().appendChild(object);
  var la = ge.createLookAt('');
  la.set(-1.251336, -78.443817, 7000, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 
         177, 65, 500);
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);         
}

//var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(-1.402002,-78.409471)); // latitude, longitude 
//   map.addOverlay(marker); 

function failureCB(errorCode) {
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can [set the fly to speed](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/camera_control#flytospeed) to `SPEED_TELEPORT` before loading the abstract view.

This setting will make globe instantaneously fly-to the desired location rather than 'swooping in'. If regular movement should be restored then after you have your initial view you can set the speed back to the default setting.

For example the following function can be used to instantaneously fly-to the desired location.
The method accepts any [KmlAbstractView](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_abstract_view), i.e. a [KmlCamera](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_camera) or [KmlLookAt](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_look_at) as its single parameter.

```
// fly-to a view using SPEED_TELEPORT
function teleport(abstractView) {
  var oldSpeed = ge.getOptions().getFlyToSpeed(); .
  ge.getOptions().setFlyToSpeed(ge.SPEED_TELEPORT); 
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(abstractView);  // Wooosh!
  ge.getOptions().setFlyToSpeed(oldSpeed); 
}
```

Further to this to make sure that the transition is not shown at all for an initial position you can make the teleport move before setting the `GEWindow` visibility to True. For example.

```
function initCB(instance) {
   ge = instance;
   var la = ge.createLookAt('');
   la.set(-1.251336, -78.443817, 7000, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 177, 65, 500);
   teleport(la); // set the position
   ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true); // now display the window
   //etc..
```

Comment: This is quite useful.  One small glitch still: the plug-in briefly displays the earth from space before arriving at the proper look at.  Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: Update: I improvised a way.  By starting the init callback function with `ge.getWindow().setVisibility(false);` and putting `ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);` after the setAbstractView call, it avoids displaying the earth from space, even briefly.

Comment: That is correct, you can set the position before making the plugin window visible.